# flutter full screen using SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky); not working correctly

Tags: flutter, dart, fullscreen

Trying to set app as full screen using `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky);`
it hides the bottom navigation bar but is inconsistent sometimes a white space appears at the bottom, and the top status bar part is just a black space always [image: status blck spaace]

```
void main() async {
 await setupServiceLocator();
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

 await SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky);

   runApp(ProviderScope(child: DevicePreview(
      enabled:false,//!kReleaseMode,
      builder: (context) => MyApp())));
}
```

how to resolve this ? already tried     `<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>` in the styles.xml file but no change.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my code, it is worked for me
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfE6y.png

```
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual,
      overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.top]);
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIChangeCallback((systemOverlaysAreVisible) async {
    _debouncer.run(() {
      SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual,
          overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.top]);
    });
  });

  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: AppColors.transparent,
    statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light,
    statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
    systemNavigationBarColor: AppColors.transparent,
    systemNavigationBarDividerColor: null,
    systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
  ));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. If possible, please 

[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78222955/edit)

your post to add further details, such as explanations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information in [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) - *"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."*  It might be helpful to review some highly upvoted answers as examples to follow Thanks!